# How would I solve this sequence problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

> Given $a_1 = 4$, $a_2 = -2$, and $a_{n} = 2a_{n–2} - 3a_{n–1}$, what is the smallest value of $n$ for which $|a_{n}| > 1\,000\,000$?

I know you can go through and test numbers until you reach 1,000,000. However, is there a way to solve this problem by not merely checking numbers.

Comment: Please use mathjax (latex related, adapted for the web) to put the problem in a better shape, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Comment: I'm not really sure how solving the recurrence relation is going to help, because the solution is nasty as all hell.

$$a_n = \left( \frac 52 + \frac{23}{2 \sqrt{17}} \right) \left( \frac{-3 + \sqrt{17}}{2} \right)^n + \left( \frac 52 - \frac{23}{2 \sqrt{17}} \right) \left( \frac{-3 - \sqrt{17}}{2} \right)^n$$

([Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+the+recurrence++relation+a(1)+%3D+4,+a(2)+%3D+-2,+a(n)+%3D+2*a(n-2)+-+3*a(n-1)) offers a different solution but it doesn't look any better.)

Comment: @ Eevee Trainer i think checking numbers is the best way to handle this question, infact after using a computer for calculations i found that $n=12$ is indeed the smallest number!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Yeah, I'm inclined to agree logo. If nothing else, no more pleasant a method comes to mind

Comment: Thirded. I just spend a good half hour trying to find a nice way to do this. The closed form is terrible, and if you write $a_n=cr_1^n+dr_2^n$, the triangle inequality gives the bound $a_n\le 10^6$ for all $n\le -21$, which is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simplify the expression as much as you can, you should get
$$a_n=\frac 1 {34}\big( \left(85-23 \sqrt{17 } \right)\,r_1^n+ \left(85+23 \sqrt{17 } \right)\,r_2^n \big)$$ where
$$r_1=-\frac{\sqrt{17}+3}{2} \qquad \text{and} \qquad r_2=\frac{\sqrt{17}-3}{2} $$
You can notice that $r_2$ is quite small. So, for "large" values of $n$, an asymptotic is
$$a_n \sim (-1)^{n+1} \,\frac{\left(23 \sqrt{17 }-85 \right)}{34} \left(\frac{\sqrt{17}+3}{2}\right)^n$$ So, if you want $|a_n| \approx 10^k $, taking logarithms you need to compute $n$ such that
$$\log(10^k)=\log\left(\frac{23 \sqrt{17 }-85 }{34}\right)+n \log\left(\frac{\sqrt{17}+3}{2}\right)$$ Applied to the case where $k=6$, this would give as a real $n\approx 11.85$. So, $12$ seems to be a good candidate.

But, for $a_n$ itself, you must take care that the sequence alternates between positive and negative numbers.